# Unload AppDomain crashes the program

Tags: c#, appdomain

I created a new AppDomain => NewAppDomain

When i try to unload the `NewAppDomain` occurs the exception:
*"LocalDataStoreSlot storage has been freed."* and my program is crashing.
Why the exception occurs ?

some code:

```
public class ActivatedAddIn : DisposableClass
{
    public AppDomain AppDomain { get; internal set; }

    internal IBaseAddInApp Proxy { get;  set; }

    public void Shutdown()
    {
      Dispose();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        //Here the crash :((( 
        AppDomain.Unload(AppDomain);
        AppDomain = null;
        Proxy = null;
        GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
        GC.Collect();

    }
}
```

on window closed event of an add-in:

```
ActivatedAddIn runnedAddIn = RunnedAddIns.FirstOrDefault(item => item.ActivatedAddIn.Proxy.RunnedId == runnedAddInId);
if(runnedAddIn == null) return;
RunnedAddIns.Remove(runnedAddIn);
runnedAddIn.ShutdownAddIn();
```

Comment: You are going to need to provide some code to get any sensible answers.

Comment: Dou you have some code for us? In general look at this simple article on msdn: [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c5b8a8f9.aspx)

Comment: I really can't understand what happens and why calls AppDomain.SetData(it is here occurs the exception) method while unloading a domain...

Comment: I realized that when i create user controls(Window, etc.)  the exception occurs on unloading AppDomain, if new AppDomain doesn't contain any user controls AppDomain unloads perfectly(i tested load/unload 10/15 times and the exception wasn't thrown). How to resolve the issue?